# Connecting to MongoLab shell (Azure cloud server)

Tags: mongodb, shell, azure

So i spent quite a bit of time pulling my hair out trying to connect to our MongoLab account at work with a command line shell. I followed the instructions [here](http://docs.mongolab.com/connecting/#connect-string) but no for some reason mongoDB would always return: `Error: 18 { code: 18, ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth fails"}`

My user name and password were coming from my database under the `users` collections which worked fine with my Node.js driver but wouldn't work with my shell.

The question is: where does one find the correct user name and password to connect to MongoLabs with the mongodb shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the user name and password to connect and authorize with the shell aren't found in MongoLabs but in Azure's portal.

Log into your Azure account, in the left column scroll down to `Add-Ons` and click.

You should see a MongoLab's. Go ahead and click on that.

From there click on `Connection Info` at the bottom of the window and it will display a string similar to this:

```
mongodb://username:password@ds012345.mongolab.com:56789/mongolab
```

go ahead and copy and paste that username and password into your shell with this command :

```
mongo ds012345.mongolab.com:56789/dbname -u dbuser -p dbpassword
```

NOTE: Your command will look different because you're using a different MongoLabs account.